# Reading from pipe stdout waits infinitely

Tags: python, matlab, pipe, stdout

I have python script that sends commands to matlab script using `subprocess.Popen`. Matlab, in turn, sends back data to python, using stdout of the pipe. Communication between Python and Matlab should run infinitely, however, once retrieved information from Matlab, python should run its own functions. Problem is that python waits for information infinitely from Matlab. Code will make it clear:

```
class MatlabWrapper(object):
def __init__(self, barrier_fullname=DEFAULT_BARRIER_FULLNAME):
    self.barrier_fullname = barrier_fullname

def run(self):
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(
        'matlab -nodisplay -nosplash', shell=True, 
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=DEVNULL)

    #self.process.stdin.write('matlabpool 8;\n')
    self.process.stdin.flush()

def execute(self, cmd):
    try:
        os.remove(self.barrier_fullname)
    except OSError:
        pass

    self.process.stdin.write(cmd)
    self.process.stdin.write('; !touch %s\n' % self.barrier_fullname)
    self.process.stdin.flush()

    while True:
        try:
            with open(self.barrier_fullname, 'rb') as _:
                break
        except IOError:
            time.sleep(0)

    os.remove(self.barrier_fullname)
while True:
    line = self.process.stdout.readline()
    if line:
        print '>>>' + line.rstrip()
    else:
        break
```

After creating an instance of MatlabWrapper, I launch `run` function that initializes pipe. Then I send command to execute to Matlab, and wait when it outputs some information (using `printf`). After reading stdout line by line, it stops at line `line = self.process.stdout.readline()` and waits for more information from matlab.

What I want is that when there is no information in stdout python will finish `execute` function. How should I do this?

Comment: Are you closing the pipe? You'll only get an `EOF` (which would make `readline` return an empty string) once the pipe is closed on the other end.

Comment: Where I should close the pipe?

Comment: I mean how Matlab can close the pipe? Besides, as I described I need communication to run infinitely (the reason being it takes too much time to set up environment in matlab). So probably closing pipe is not a solution here.

Comment: The other thing to do then is to somehow have MATLAB output some custom "work's done" flag line, and check for that in python.